# How to stop IDEA/AndroidStudio from producing device 'emulator-5670' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Android Studio keeps spamming me with messages about an emulator that I never created.

I have setup a brand new Linux develment environment with adb/android sdk/tools/Android Studio etc.

I use my real device for development, not a emulator

I keep seeing spam in Android Studio's (IDEA 15 to be honest) tab for `ADB Logs`, and there is a distracting visual jank/hitch where the dropdown list resizes itself every time this message prints:

```
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5670: device 'emulator-5670' not found
```

I tried creating an emulator device, named the same, but to no avail. A different device called emulator-xxxx was then showing up in the ADB Logs

I tried restarting the adb with `killall adb`, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your `adb` software is out of date, or not up to par with what is distributed with Ubuntu

Open a terminal, and

```
 $ sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
 $ adb devices

adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

It was at this point that I solved the issue above.

Here is some more information about the latest android tools adb distributed by Ubuntu that I now have installed.

```
apt-cache policy android-tools-adb
android-tools-adb:
  Installed: 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23
  Candidate: 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23
  Version table:
*** 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```